# Alternative for batch job scheduling (in compute pool)

Tags: load-balancing, batch-processing, job-scheduling

Since I don't have root rights on the machines in a compute pool, and thus cannot adapt the load parameters of atd for batch, I'm looking for an alternative way to do job scheduling. Since the machines are used by multiple users, it should be able to take the load into account. Optionally, I'm looking for a way to do this for all the machines it the pool, I.e. there is one central queue with jobs that need to be ran, and a script that distributes them (over ssh) over the machines that are under a certain load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First: go talk to the system administrators of the compute pool. Enterprise wide job schedulers have become a rather common component in infrastructures these days. Typically, these schedulers do not take into account system load though.

If the above doesn't lead to a good solution, you should carefully consider what load your jobs will impose on the machine: your jobs could be stressing the cpu more, consume large amounts of memory, generate lots of network or disk IO activity. Consequently, determining whether your job should start may depend on a lot of measurement, some of which you would not be able to do as an ordinary user (depends a bit on the kind of OS you are running, and how tight security is). In any case: you would only be able to take into account the load at the job's start up. Obviously, if every user would do this, you're back at square one in no time...

It might be a better idea to see with your system administrator if they have some sort of resource controls in place (e.g. projects in Solaris) through which they can make sure your batches are not tearing down the nodes in the compute pool. Next, write your batch jobs in such a way that they can cope with the OS declining requests for resources.

EDIT: As for the distributed nature: queueing up the jobs and having clients on all nodes point to the same queue, consuming as much as they can in the context of the resource controls...

Comment: Thanks! Would there be any alternatives when this doesn't work out?